# Bloom filter in Java

Tags: java, hash, bloom-filter

Basically I have to implement a bloom filter and test it with char 'a' to 'z' and 'A' to 'Z' (easy and done).

Then I have to test for false positives but the requirements say to use "aa" to "ZZ" (strings) to count the false positives (not done).

Any idea what that means?

Answer (score 3):

false positive requires actual set of data, I think what your professor meant was: add 'a'-'z','A'-'Z' to the filter (actual data) now, check for all the strings "aa"-"ZZ", count the number of false positives (all positives will be false, since none of them are in the data) and extract the ratio: `#false_positives/#strings_in_range("aa","ZZ")`

**EDIT:** at comments @Bill asked how to iterate over "aa"-"ZZ", here is a simple code snap of how to do it.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (Character c = 'a';c<='z';c++) { 
     String lower = c.toString();
     String upper = c.toString().toUpperCase();
     for (Character k = 'a';k<='z';k++) { 
            set.add(lower + k.toString());
            set.add(lower + k.toString().toUpperCase());
            set.add(upper + k.toString());
            set.add(upper + k.toString().toUpperCase());
     }
}
```

Comment: that doesnt really clear anything up for me, sorry. I added the characters, thats fine. What I dont understand is why we use a string to count false positives, the hash function takes an int.

Comment: this answers assumes the hash functions can handle String as an input, as well as char.

Comment: OK, so how do I iterate from "aa" to "zz" then?

Comment: @Bill: this is a different question, but just build them and insert into a set, see edit for a code sample.

Comment: @Bill: see edit how to build a `Set<String>` containing those strings.